# How to use delegation for a slide-out menu in an iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to call a method in a class using delegation, but currently when I call the delegate method the app is crashing with the following error message,

`unrecognized selector sent to instance`

I have a slide-out menu which contains a table view that is loading a view when the table view item is seleted with the following,

```
// ViewControllerRootHomeLeftPanel.m
    -(void)showCalibrate{
        ViewControllerCalibrate *calibrateVC = [[ViewControllerCalibrate alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerCalibrate" bundle:nil];
        [((ViewControllerRootHome *)self.parentViewController).viewControllerRootHomeCenter addChildViewController:calibrateVC];
        [calibrateVC.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 64.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

        [calibrateVC didMoveToParentViewController:((ViewControllerRootHome *)self.parentViewController).viewControllerRootHomeCenter];

        [((ViewControllerRootHome *)self.parentViewController).viewControllerRootHomeCenter.view addSubview:calibrateVC.view];

    // the below delegate method hides the left panel vc (table view) after loading a view on the root home center vc.
        [myDelegate loadVCRH];
    }
```

I then setup a delegate method in the ViewControllerCalibrate VC as such,

```
// ViewControllerCalibrate.h
@protocol ViewControllerCalibrateDelegate;
@protocol ViewControllerCalibrateDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) removeCalibrateView;
@end

@interface ViewControllerCalibrate : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ViewControllerCalibrateDelegate> delegate;
@end

// ViewControllerCalibrate.m
- (void)removeCalibrateView {
    NSLog(@"removeCalibrateView method called");
}
```

I then try to call the `removeCalibrateView` method within the `ViewControllerRootHomeCenter`

```
// ViewControllerRootHomeCenter.m
- (void)removeSubViews{
    for (UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]){
        NSLog(@"subviews = %@",[self.view subviews]);
        if (subview.tag == 3) {
            // the below delegate method call is causing the app to crash.
            [self removeCalibrateView];
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What was the unrecognized selector and what type of object was it trying to call the selector on? There should be more to the error than `unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

Comment: "when I call the delegate method". You are not calling the delegate method - you are calling removeCalibrateView on self. Self is an object of type ViewControllerRootHomeCenter. You need to call it on the delegate member variable. But you have added the delegate as part of ViewControllerCalibrate not on ViewControllerRootHomeCenter so I'm confused why you have added it to ViewControllerCalibrate if you are trying to call it from withinViewControllerRootHomeCenter

Comment: You seem to be confused as to how delegates work. You call the delegate method on the delegate (`[delegate removeCalibrateView]`) in the class that creates the protocol, in your case, that is `ViewControllerCalibrate`. The method should be *implemented* in the class that is the delegate.